# Arcmap classification data exclusion

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap

I am presenting some percentage change data, and I created a color ramp such that negative values are shades of red and the positive values are shades are blue.

I want to use a custom classification with data exclusion so that I create a classification scale for negative values and scale for positive values.

However, data exclusion doesn't seem to be working.

Is there a different way to achieve my goal? I am using Arcmap 10.1.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what I would do in this situation would be to have two versions of the same dataset in the map. One would use a definition query to exclude the negative values and it would classify the positive values. Then the other would have a definition query excluding positive values and classifying the negative values.